# Change the Array Format

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a page where it prints out this value:

```
"Firstname","Ana","George","Wilson"
"Lastname","Smith","Spencer","Carey"
"Age","18","20","22"
```

I get the values of these using file_get_contents and str_getcsv.

```
$array= str_getcsv($test);
```

The Array results that I get is this

```
Array ( [0] =>
"Firstname"
    [1] => 'Ana'
    [2] => 'George'
    [3] => 'Wilson'
"Lastname"
    [4] => 'Smith'
    [5] => 'Spencer'
    [6] => 'Carey'
"Age"
    [7] => 18
    [8] => 20
    [9] => 22
))
```

Is there anyway I can change the Array format into this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Ana'
            [1] => 'George'
            [2] => 'Wilson'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Smith'
            [1] => 'Spencer'
            [2] => 'Carey'
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 22
        )
)
```

Comment: `The Array results that I get is this`-> i don't think it's correct array structure. Please check and correct it. Do `var_export($explode);` and add that output into the question

Comment: Hi my apologies, i tried using str_getcsv instead of explode, I have now edited my question thank you

Comment: Can you please check my answer once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `file_get_contents()` and `str_getcsv()`, i will recomend you to use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Do like below:-

```
<?php

$test = file('test.txt'); // you can add your file url here

echo "<pre/>";print_r($test);// initial array

foreach($test as &$te){
     $new_array = explode(',',$te);
     unset($new_array[0]);
     $te = array_values($new_array);
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($test); // modified and desired array
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much! it did get my desired results using this. Im using file_get_contents() using a URL, i tried it and it works as well. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @c18online glad to help you :):)

Comment: I used the exact code that you have suggested, I just replaced txt to url :)

Answer (score 0):

To change the given array to a specified format:

```
$array = ['Firstname' => ['Ana', 'George', 'Wilson'], 'Lastname' => ['Smith', 'Spencer', 'Carey'], 'Age' => [18, 20, 22]];

$new_array = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $new_array[] = $value;
}

print_r($new_array);

Array
(
    [Firstname] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ana
            [1] => George
            [2] => Wilson
        )

    [Lastname] => Array
        (
            [0] => Smith
            [1] => Spencer
            [2] => Carey
        )

    [Age] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 22
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This bro i hope i can help:

```
$array = array(0=> array(
              'firstname' => array(1 => 'Ana', 2 => 'George', 3=>'Wilson'),
               'lastname' => array(4=>'Smith', 5=>'Spencer', 6=> 'Carey'),
                'age' => array(7=>18,8=>20,9=>22)
               ));

 $newArray = array();
 echo "<pre/>";print_r($array);
 foreach($array as $key=>$new){


   foreach($new as $k=>$d){

      $newArray[] = array_values($d);
   }
 }
 echo "</br>New Array Format: </br>";
 echo "<pre/>";print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: Hi @dee i also tried this one, and it also got my desired results thank you :)